# Lambda capture shared_ptr member

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11, lambda, smart-pointers

I have a class `OpenGLRenderer` which has a class member `mMemoryAllocator` that is a `std::shared_ptr<MemoryAllocator>`. The reason I keep the memory allocator in a shared_ptr, is because even if the `shared_ptr<Texture>` returned below outlives it's creator   the`OpenGLRenderer`, the `MemoryAllocator` instance will still be valid if I capture it by value, as it increments the ref count:

```
std::shared_ptr<Texture> OpenGLRenderer::CreateTexture(TextureType textureType, const std::vector<uint8_t>& textureData, uint32_t textureWidth, uint32_t textureHeight, TextureFormat textureFormat)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<Texture>(mMemoryAllocator->AllocateObject<Texture>(
                                    textureData, textureWidth, textureHeight,
                                    textureFormat, textureType, mLogger), 
                                    [=](Texture* texture) { 
                                        mMemoryAllocator
                                         ->DeallocateObject<Texture>(texture); 
                                    });
}
```

...But, it dosn't work. If `OpenGLRenderer` goes out of scope before the `std::shared_ptr<Texture>`, the `std::shared_ptr<MemoryAllocator>` becomes corrupted, and thus the lambda expression goes bonkers. What have I done wrong?

Comment: When asking a question, make it as easy as possible for others to read your code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem in this case is that lambdas don't capture members of the object, but the `this` pointer. A simple workaround is to create a local variable and bind that:

```
std::shared_ptr<Texture> 
OpenGLRenderer::CreateTexture(TextureType textureType, 
                              const std::vector<uint8_t>& textureData, 
                              uint32_t textureWidth, uint32_t textureHeight, 
                              TextureFormat textureFormat)

{
    std::shared_ptr<AllocatorType> allocator = mMemoryAllocator;
    return std::shared_ptr<Texture>(mMemoryAllocator->AllocateObject<Texture>(
                                    textureData, textureWidth, textureHeight,
                                    textureFormat, textureType, mLogger), 
                                    [=](Texture* texture) { 
                                        allocator
                                         ->DeallocateObject<Texture>(texture); 
                                    });
}
```

Comment: Why dosn't the '=' help in capturing?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan: To make a long story short, the lambda in your question is processed as `this->mMemoryAllocator->DeallocateObject<Texture>(texture);`, the local *object* that is used is `this`, and `[=]` will capture that. Not the members of the object you use, but the `this` pointer. You are capturing by value, just not the right thing